# Boost asynchronous server accepting connection twice

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am working on a boost.asio asynchronous server.
At the moment the server code is very simple. It accept a connection from a client and on accepting the connection, it send a READY message to client. The client print the READY message and then allow user to write any message in the client console. any message typed in client will be sent to the server. The server print the message and byte size of the message, then send back the same message to client with an extra "... OK" string.

Now what I am experiencing is after the server accepting the connection and sending the first "READY" message, it accepting another connection and instantiating new connection class. But after that all is going as expected.

So, I am not quite sure why after calling async_write (to send the READY message) it is re_initiating another connection. However, the call back function of the async_write (which is handle_write) is getting called!

Here is my server and client code:

main.cpp

```
#include "casperServer.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
      casperServer s("0.0.0.0", "7000");
      s.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

server.cpp

```
#include "casperServer.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>


casperServer::casperServer(const std::string& address, const std::string& port)
    :_acceptor(_ioService),
     _connection()
{

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);

    _acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
    _acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
    _acceptor.bind(endpoint);
    _acceptor.listen();


    //Starting the acceptor
    //start_accept();
}

void casperServer::run()
{
    std::cout<< "Running ioService" <<std::endl;
    start_accept();
    _ioService.run();

}

void casperServer::start_accept()
{
    std::cout<< "Creating connection instance ..." <<std::endl;
    _connection.reset(new casperConnection(_ioService));

    std::cout<< "Accept connection" <<std::endl;
    _acceptor.async_accept( _connection->socket(),
                            boost::bind(    &casperServer::handle_accept, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));


}

void casperServer::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{

    std::cout<< "Connection accepted ..." <<std::endl;

    if (!e)
    {
        _connection->start();
    }

    std::cout<< "Restarting connection accept ..." <<std::endl;
    start_accept();
}
```

Connection.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "casperConnection.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

casperConnection::casperConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    :_socket(io_service)
{

}


boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& casperConnection::socket()
{
    return _socket;
}

void casperConnection::start()
{
      std::cout<< "Writing to client ->" <<std::endl;
      std::cout << "...sigaling READY"<< std::endl;
      boost::asio::async_write( _socket, boost::asio::buffer("Server READY ..."),
                                boost::bind(    &casperConnection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void casperConnection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::cout<<"[Handle_read]!"<<std::endl;

    _inputBuffer.clear();

    std::copy(_readBuffer.begin(), _readBuffer.begin()+bytes_transferred, std::back_inserter(_inputBuffer));

    std::cout << "Byte recieved: "<<bytes_transferred<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "Data: "<<_inputBuffer<< std::endl;

    _inputBuffer= _inputBuffer + " ...OK";

    boost::asio::async_write(   _socket, boost::asio::buffer(_inputBuffer, _inputBuffer.length()),
                                boost::bind(    &casperConnection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}


void casperConnection::handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    std::cout<<"[Handle_write]!"<<std::endl;

    _socket.async_read_some(    boost::asio::buffer(_readBuffer),
                                boost::bind(    &casperConnection::handle_read, shared_from_this(),
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

    if(_readBuffer.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<"Buffer empty!"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is my client code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "Client.h"

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Client _client("127.0.0.1", "7000");

    _client.Connect();

    return 0;
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

Client::Client(const std::string& address, const std::string& port)
{
    std::cout<<"Client CTOR "<<std::endl;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);

    initConnection(endpoint);
}

Client::~Client()
{

}

void Client::initConnection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep)
{
    std::cout<<"Initializing connection "<<std::endl;

    _connection.reset(new clientConnection(_ioService));
    _connection->socket().async_connect(ep, boost::bind(&Client::on_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}


void Client::Connect()
{
    std::cout<<"Calling ioService run."<<std::endl;
    _ioService.run();
}


void Client::on_connect(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{
    std::cout << "On connection accept ..." << std::endl;

    if (!e)
    {
        _connection->start();
    }
}
```

Connection.cpp

```
#include  "clientConnection.h"
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>


clientConnection::clientConnection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    :_socket(io_service)
{
    std::cout<<"Client Connection CTOR"<<std::endl;
}

clientConnection::~clientConnection()
{

}

boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& clientConnection::socket()
{
    return _socket;
}

void clientConnection::start()
{

     _socket.async_read_some(   boost::asio::buffer(_buffer),
                                boost::bind(&clientConnection::on_read, shared_from_this(),
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));


}


void clientConnection::on_read(const boost::system::error_code& e, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{

    std::cout<<"Server msg: "<<_buffer.c_array()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<bytes_transferred<< " bytes read."<<std::endl;

    _buffer.assign(0);

    std::cout<<">>";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout<<"Sending to server: "<<input<<std::endl;


    boost::asio::async_write(   _socket, boost::asio::buffer(input, input.length()),
                                boost::bind(    &clientConnection::on_write, shared_from_this(),
                                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}

void clientConnection::on_write(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{

         _socket.async_read_some(   boost::asio::buffer(_buffer),
                                    boost::bind(&clientConnection::on_read, shared_from_this(),
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
```

Here is my output in console:

```
Running ioService
Creating connection instance ...
Accept connection
Connection accepted ...
Writing to client ->
...sigaling READY
Restarting connection accept ...
Creating connection instance ...
Accept connection
[Handle_write]!
```

You can see, just after writing the READY command, the server is initializing another connection and I am not sure why.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is no problem of accepting another connection. It's only the way you have added the prints.

```
void casperServer::start_accept()
{
    std::cout<< "Creating connection instance ..." <<std::endl;
    _connection.reset(new casperConnection(_ioService));

    std::cout<< "Accept connection" <<std::endl;
    _acceptor.async_accept( _connection->socket(),
                            boost::bind(    &casperServer::handle_accept, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));


}

void casperServer::handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& e)
{

    std::cout<< "Connection accepted ..." <<std::endl;

    if (!e)
    {
        _connection->start();
    }

    std::cout<< "Restarting connection accept ..." <<std::endl;
    start_accept();
}
```

As per the above code, after accepting the first connection, `handle_accept` will get called in which you start the connection instance and then call `start_accept` again. And inside this `start_accept` you print "Creating connection ...." and "Accept connection...." before dispatching the `accept` task to `io_service`.

From your log:

```
Running ioService
Creating connection instance ...
Accept connection
Connection accepted ...  // This shows when connection was actually accepted
Writing to client ->
...sigaling READY
Restarting connection accept ...
Creating connection instance ...
Accept connection // This is a print just before dispatching the accept task to io_service, so not actually accepting a connection
[Handle_write]!
```

Comment: Okay, I think I understand it now, is it like for the nature of asynchronous function, inside _connection->start(), after async_write is called, _connection->start() is returned and then start_accept is called for the 2nd time?  But for the first accepted connection, the read and write functions continues in the loop? ... and the acceptor keep witing for a 2nd connection?